# How to get multiple ibeacons using CoreLocation, objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I'm using the following code to assign a beacon uuid:

```
NSUUID *uuid=[[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"1234545-12F-...-...-DGS457DHSJFHSD"];
```

But I need to detect several beacons with different uuid's. 
How do I do it? Is there is any method to detect any possible beacon(with uuid unknown by the app) near the device?

I would like a method(if any) in Objective-C.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You simply create multiple beaconRegions and register them wit your `CLLocationManager`. There is example code in the Apple Core Location Programming Guide. You cannot scan for "all possible beacons"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS it is not possible to detect all iBeacons.  You must tell `CoreLocation` the ProximityUUIDs you want to detect up front.  You may register up to 20 different ProximityUUIDs to detect at any given time by registering different `CLBeaconRegion` instances, each with a different ProximityUUID.

Android, Linux and OSX do not have this restriction.

[See here for details.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html)